# Trying to access information within localStorage

Tags: reactjs, object, local-storage

I am trying to access information with-in localStorage from one component to another, specifically the name of the user on their profile.  I am able to access up to the object holding all of the profile information like name, email, address etc.  However when I try to extract just the name I am unsure of how to do so, or if its even possible.

right now im trying...

```
 console.log(localStorage.document)
```

this gets me the an object holding all the data in localStorage...

```
{"name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@aol.com","phone":"0000000000","address1":"123","address2":"123","addresscitystate":"Seattle, WA","addresszip":"00000"}
```

yet I cant seem to access any further then that.  I attempted to just do [0] at the end to get the index but im getting just the letter back for that specific index not the actual object I want.

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: If what it returns is an object, you can get the value you want by using that property's key - e.g. `localStorage.document.name`.

Comment: in your output is not an array, why are you using a numeric index?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this one, For extracting the specific property from localStorage you can do this:

```
let item = localStorage.getItem("name")
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is.
First you need to extract the localStorage item

```
let savedItem = localStorage.getItem("username")
```

"Username" is the name of the item that is save in you localstorage.
The Complete guide for the localstorage usage is as follow.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage